# weeget: unable to parse xml list of scripts

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, irc, weechat

am new and just started using weechat, irc terminal client. And also installed *weeget* to help me install weechat scripts directly on my *weechat-curses* opened window.

Now problem arises as I was done downloading weeget in, `~/.weechat/scripts/autoload/.` then entered in my *weechat-curses* and joined irc.freenode.net server I tried the command /weeget list which should list available scripts for download but it took a long time downloading (that explains my slow internet) but this never completed for a while,
then I tried listing my installed scripts with `/weeget listinstalled`
and it's when I started getting the error, **weeget:unable to parse xml list of scripts**.
Exited with `/exit` command, then reopened weechat, connected to server, tried to list installed scripts only.. still same error.
Please help.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am so new yet, so outdated, there is already support for searching and downloading scripts from weechat itself, I didn't know this until I watched on a youtube video, anyway the `/script` command directly from weechat comes built in for newer versions I guess, and it worked magic..
Cheers..!